# ActiveRecord query throught join table and parent_id

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, relational-database

I'm studying deeper and deeper RoRails and i am stuck in front of datas we gave me to reproduce on this lovely framework.
Let me show you first my tables and the models associates.

```
  create_table "skills", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.bigint "parent_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["parent_id"], name: "index_skills_on_parent_id"
  end

  create_table "skills_users", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "skill_id", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.index ["skill_id", "user_id"], name: "index_skills_users_on_skill_id_and_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "points"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

And models:

```
class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  has_many :children, class_name: "Skill", foreign_key: :parent_id
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "Skill", foreign_key: :parent_id, optional: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :points, presence: true
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
end
```

The goal is to class Skills, fetch Skills children and count Users'points in each parent Skill. Here is an example of data

```
SKILLS
+-----------------------+
|ID|NAME      |PARENT_ID|
+-----------------------+
|1 |Football  |         |
+-----------------------+
|2 |Basketball|         |
+-----------------------+
|3 |Foot      |1        |
+-----------------------+
|4 |Basket    |2        |
+-----------------------+
|5 |Soccer    |1        |
+-----------------------+

SKILLS_USERS
+-------------------+
|ID|SKILL_ID|USER_ID|
+-------------------+
|1 |1       |1      | 
+-------------------+
|2 |1       |2      | 
+-------------------+
|3 |3       |3      | 
+-------------------+
|4 |2       |4      | 
+-------------------+
|5 |5       |5      |
+-------------------+

USERS
+---------+
|ID|POINTS|
+---------+
|1 |100   |
+---------+
|2 |200   |
+---------+
|3 |100   |
+---------+
|4 |50    |
+---------+
|5 |10    |
+---------+
```

The request expected should look like this :

```
+--------------------------------+
|ID|NAME      |POINTS|USERS_COUNT|
+--------------------------------+
|1 |Football  |410   |4          |
+--------------------------------+
|2 |Basketball|50    |1          |
+--------------------------------+
```

I'm trying first to answer it in pure sql with this query:

```
SELECT id , Name , count ( points)  as POINTS , count (USER_ID ) as USERS_COUNT 
FROM SKILLS 
INNER JOIN SKILLS as SK ON id = SK.parent_id 
INNER JOIN SKILLS_USERS AS su ON su.skill_id = id 
INNER JOIN USERS AS User ON SU.USER_ID = User.id
```

But it seems i'm wrong somewhere.

I think ActiveRecord way is much plaisant, ruby is magic. What is the ActiveRecord way to do this kind of request thgrouht to a join table and where we select only parent Skills ?

Answer (score 1):

If the intended purpose is to record the score of each user for a given skill then you need to place it on the join table and not the users table.

```
 create_table "skills", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.bigint "parent_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["parent_id"], name: "index_skills_on_parent_id"
  end

  create_table "user_skills", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "skill_id", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id", null: false
    t.integer "points"
    t.index ["skill_id", "user_id"], name: "index_skills_users_on_skill_id_and_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

And you want to setup the associations with `has_many through:` and not `has_and_belongs_to_many` which does not allow you to query the join table directly or access that `points` column.

```
class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_skills
  has_many :users, through: :user_skills
end

class UserSkill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :skill
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_skills
  has_many :users, through: :user_skills
end
```

You query is also much more complex than needed and still misses the mark. You can get the desired result by querying the skills table and joining `user_skills`.

```
SELECT skills.id, skills.name, 
  SUM(user_skills.points) AS points, 
  count(user_skills.user_id) AS user_count 
FROM "skills" 
INNER JOIN "user_skills" ON "user_skills"."skill_id" = "skills"."id" 
GROUP BY skills.id
```

Which we can do in ActiveRecord with:

```
Skill.joins(:user_skills)
     .select('skills.id, skills.name, SUM(user_skills.points) AS points, COUNT(user_skills.user_id) AS user_count')
     .group('skills.id')
```

This will return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` of `Skill` records with additional `.points` and `.user_count` attributes.

Comment: Joining the "parent" and "child" skills together and getting a collective aggregate is much more complex and will most likely require a db specific solution to perform it effectively.

Comment: Thank you max, i will try your solution this afternoon !